# Is it ethical(or legal) for an HR to delay permanent contract and notify your team mates about your new assets?

Tags: human-resources, contracts, philippines

I was with this company where I pass the probationary period and they gave me a contract for permanent position after 2 weeks of the said period. Say my probation period duration is until October  1 then they gave me the permanent contract on October 17 is this legal?

Unfortunately I made(or they made me) mistakes due to my skill set was not parallel with the task -I'm a software developer, and they made me do some QA level tasks within my waiting period of my permanent contract. I don't have any training just an orientation regarding their basic policies(Eg. wearing ids, logging in and out).

Then after i signed the permanent contract, after a week, I literally hand my sealed letter for a request for a requirement for my housing needs to be pass to the accounting department. And after a day or 2 my office mates are buzzing about my housing that I don't even shared to them. The document that i hand to the HR deals with tax and it states that it is needed for the housing. My co-workers thinks that I'm rich so they act insecure but honestly its a family shared house.

**My Questions are:**
Is it ethical(or legal) for an HR to delay permanent contract? 
And Notify your teammates about your new assets?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you tell us what country this is? A lot of what you're talking about seems country-specific.

Comment: Im currently based in the Philippines.

Comment: Do you even need to ask if it was ethical? small minded people...They tipically ask IT people tasks that are not appropriate to them because they feel treathned by not having a speciality. Do not let them play you, grow some spine and confidence. I bet you are young too...It was as much their mistake as yours. They should not ask, you should learn that knowing when to say no is very valuable. Tell HR to uphold the confidentiality of your matters by email. Words are taken by the wind. (btw my wife is pinay)

Comment: I move from different industries which has and non hr but still in IT. I asked the "ethical" notion for my own FYI but i know its wrong its just that i just want to have concrete majority feel of it.

Answer (score 9):

No, it's not ethical for your personal information to be shared with anyone who doesn't need to know it as part of their role without your permission. It's also very unprofessional.

Many companies would view this as a serious breach of employee confidentiality and security protocols.

Comment: As I've told, i made mistakes on the said period due to lack of knowledge regards to QA testing and for that mistake i wasn't even aware that i will do that, i can't file a complaint and i think they are bargaining for that in a silent way. I don't know what to do that time I'm just staring at the monitor and my inbox was full and i don't know how to archive it on that time, i don't even know what to ask to complete the tasks.